# Notation for sum of products.

Tags: notation

I have a set of sucessive elements $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4\}$ from an arithmetic progression and I need to sum all the possible product-combinations of two elements, i.e.
$$
a_1\cdot a_2+a_1\cdot a_3+a_1\cdot a_4 +a_2\cdot a_3+a_2\cdot a_4+a_3\cdot a_4
$$ 
Is there a standard notation for this?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a couple of standard ways, but sometimes the best thing is to just use words, e.g., "the sum of all products of two elements."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sum_{1\le i\lt  j\le4}  a_ia_j$$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the sigma notation for this series is:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^3\;\sum_{k=j+1}^4 a_j a_k \;&=\; a_1 a_2 + a_1 a_3 + a_1 a_4 + a_2 a_3 +a_2 a_4 + a_3 a_4
\\ & = \sum_{1\leq j < k \leq 4} a_j a_k
\end{align}$$

Comment: The first notation is best because it's concise and much more clearly conveys there are two iterators being looped through. The third notation requires much more careful parsing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a specific notation, but your sum is

$$\frac12\left(\left(\sum a_i\right)^2-\sum a_i^2\right)$$